# Firebase Auth emulator fails intermittently with "auth/emulator-config-failed"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I'm trying to use the emulator only when it is available. `connectAuthEmulator` does not fail if the emulator is not available (i.e.: if I haven't ran `firebase emulators:start`). It fails later when I try to make a request.

To do this, I'm fetching the emulator URL (`http://localhost:9099`) using `fetch`. If the request succeeds, then I call `connectAuthEmulator`. Otherwise, I do nothing (uses the configured cloud service).

I have a problem where the `fetch` works, but `connectAuthEmulator` throws an error: `auth/emulator-config-failed`. For some weird reason, this seem to happen only when I'm logged in and I make no requests for about 15 seconds. If I spam requests however, the error never occurs.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp({ /** ... */ });
const auth = getAuth(app);

if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const authEmulatorUrl = "http://localhost:9099";
            await fetch(authEmulatorUrl);
            connectAuthEmulator(auth, authEmulatorUrl, {
                disableWarnings: true,
            });
            console.info(" Firebase Auth: emulated");
        } catch (e) {
            console.info(" Firebase Auth: not emulated");
        }
    })()
}

export { auth };
```

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

## Solution #1

First, try `http://127.0.0.1:9099` instead of `http://localhost:9099` (don't forget to set this as your emulator `host` in `firebase.json`).

## Solution #2

On top of using solution #1, try rendering your app after everything Firebase-related has init. You can do this by creating listeners on the status of your emulator connections.

#### src/config/firebase.ts

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp({ /** ... */ });
const auth = getAuth(app);

if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
    // Create listener logic
    window.emulatorsEvaluated = false;
    window.emulatorsEvaluatedListeners = [];
    window.onEmulatorsEvaluated = (listener: () => void) => {
        if (window.emulatorsEvaluated) {
            listener();
        } else {
            window.emulatorsEvaluatedListeners.push(listener);
        }
    };

    (async () => {
        try {
            // Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
            const authEmulatorUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:9099";
            await fetch(authEmulatorUrl);
            connectAuthEmulator(auth, authEmulatorUrl, {
                disableWarnings: true,
            });
            console.info(" Firebase Auth: emulated");
        } catch (e) {
            console.info(" Firebase Auth: not emulated");
        }

        // Indicate that the emulators have been evaluated
        window.emulatorsEvaluated = true;
        window.emulatorsEvaluatedListeners.forEach(
            (listener: () => void) => {
                listener();
            }
        );
    })()
}

export { auth };
```

#### src/index.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./config/firebase";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);

const Root = () => ({
  /** Some JSX */
});

if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
  window.onEmulatorsEvaluated(() => {
    root.render(<Root />);
  });
} else {
  root.render(<Root />);
}
```

## Solution #3

Forcibly change the value of `auth._canInitEmulator` (`(auth as unknown as any)._canInitEmulator` for TS) to `true`. This can have some unexpected side-effects (see answer), because some requests might go to your cloud before the emulator kicks in. This can be mitigated with solution #2 (which should prevent requests from firing)

```js
(auth as unknown as any)._canInitEmulator = true;
connectAuthEmulator(auth, authEmulatorUrl, {
  disableWarnings: true,
});
```

## Full Answer

Part of the issue here is that I was performing `connectAuthEmulator` in an async function, when the documentation clearly states it should be called immediately (and synchronously) after `getAuth`. I was aware of this, but I did not see any other alternative to the issue of connecting to the emulator only when it is available.

I dug into the source code for [connectAuthEmulator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/auth/emulator.ts#L44) ([permalink](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/87c90a78d613e22349f46bd72add64425882fc59/packages/auth/src/core/auth/emulator.ts#L44)) and found out that the error is thrown here:

```js
  _assert(
    authInternal._canInitEmulator,
    authInternal,
    AuthErrorCode.EMULATOR_CONFIG_FAILED
  );
```

`authInternal._canInitEmulator` was false when the error occurred. There is only one place where this property is set to false, in `_performFetchWithErrorHandling`, [here](https://github.dev/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/api/index.ts#L135) ([permalink](https://github.dev/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/87c90a78d613e22349f46bd72add64425882fc59/packages/auth/src/api/index.ts#L135)). This is because it's the first time it performs an API request for the Auth service. So I concluded that Firebase disallows the use of emulators after the first request using `auth` is made. This is probably to prevent making some requests on your cloud, then switching over to an emulator. So my call to `connectAuthEmulator` was probably done after a request was already made. I couldn't figure out where though. Even with my app not being loaded (solution #2), the error would still occur.

My conclusion was right, as I later found this `error.ts` file which pretty much says this:

```
    [AuthErrorCode.EMULATOR_CONFIG_FAILED]:
      'Auth instance has already been used to make a network call. Auth can ' +
      'no longer be configured to use the emulator. Try calling ' +
      '"connectAuthEmulator()" sooner.',
```

This whole investigation could've been done earlier if `FirebaseError` had shown this message instead of just `auth/emulator-config-failed`. It is visible if you `console.log(error.message)`, but I was not aware of that at the time.

For some reason, using the localhost IP instead fixed it instantly and I never had the error again. I added the solution #2 and #3 as another measure after.

Comment: solution 2 works on my end, thanks

Comment: What exactly is the syntax for setting the "host" in firebase.json for 
Solution #1?

Comment: Found it. This is what is looks like:   "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 9099
    }, 
// other stuff
}

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause of this problem comes from `React.StrictMode`. This mode will re-render twice time. It might have been initiated twice time too. I am pretty sure because when I disabled the `React.StrictMode` and refreshed the browser many times. The error does not show up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize firebase app in app.js on your project assuming your are on Vue

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

import { getAuth , connectAuthEmulator} from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {firebase config}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig) 

connectAuthEmulator( getAuth(), 'http://127.0.0.1:9099', { disableWarnings: true })
```

later, on any of your component just import getAuth()

```
const auth = getAuth()
```

// here you don't need to call connectAuthEmulator

Comment: This is exactly the nowadays solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

try http://127.0.0.1:9099 instead of http://localhost:9099  (don't forget to set this as your emulator host in firebase.json).